# Deploy WPF Application to IIS

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, iis, clickonce

I was wondering how to deploy a wpf application to an IIS application because I have the correct path etc but in the publish wizard when I click...
Browse -> Remote Site -> new web site, then enter the url it gives me an error saying that it is unable to create the website because the server doesnt have front page server extensions installed.

After some googling I found that FPSE has been discontinued and is not recommended for use, so is there a way to deploy a standalone wpf application to IIS with out FPSE?

Answer (score 2):

There are other options for deployment. You can do a network share, just make sure you enter the web address correcly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71baz9ah.aspx